# Reading USB Data From Arduino

Tags: arduino, usb

Could I read USB data from the mini USB port on an Arduino board, or is that only for installing Sketches?

Comment: What do you mean by "read USB data"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "read USB data"?  If you are referring to devices like keyboards and barcode readers, then no.  You'd have to have a board with "USB host" capabilities.  That said, apparently [there are shields](http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/) that can provide this functionality.

Comment: If it's an arduino **Leonardo**, you can have it emulate a USB keyboard/mouse/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You can read data from your Arduino, using a program like hyper-terminal on windows. To do that set up hyper-terminal to listen to which ever com port that the Arduino is on with the correct baud rate (Same as in your sketch)

The Arduino is a simple USB to Serial device as Aoi Karasu said.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux or OSX, you can use the command:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600
```

`ttyACM0` is the name of the device on my system, you may change it according to your system.
`9600` is the baud rate, again you can change it.

Comment: Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino is not a genuine USB device. It acts as a Serial to USB adapter. You have to scan all COM ports in the system to find which one is it and then talk to Arduino (perform read/write operations) using standard serial port communications that come with your development environment.

Comment: A USB serial adapter is very much a genuine USB device, unless it has been mis-implemented.  One normally uses an operating system level driver which bridges USB to the operating system's serial port API, but that's not mandated by the hardware - one could treat it as a raw USB device with something like libusb and exchange the USB data at application level.

Comment: This is not true for the Arduino Leonardo. The leonardo uses a USB-bootloader, and has no intermediate device. It can emulate any USB device the ATmega USB PHY can.